# Testing date based directory structure in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, operating-system, directory-structure

I am tasked with creating an archived directory structure for XML exports we get out of an ERP system.  The format is going to be:

```
# root/year/month/day/export#/files
archive/2013/6/18/1/files
archive/2013/6/18/2/files
```

In order to accomplish this I have written a simple function that takes todays date, finds the correct folder, increments the export #, and moves the files appropriately.

My problem is, how do I test the function is actually working without implementing the function in the test?

EDIT: The export# is automatically incremented.  The first export for the day will be 1, the second 2, so on.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to cover the export feature with unit tests. You can do the following:

- find last export id
- create new export id directory
- put a meta file, e.g. empty `.processing` file
- process the export
- remove the meta file after everything is done

You can check if there is a process executing the export function by checking if the empty file exists. But this has nothing to do with python I guess.